# ST2 Keymap: Args for "expand_selection"

Tags: sublimetext2

Does anyone know how to edit the "expand_selection" keymap in Sublime Text 2 so that it only selects the current line and not the line break that follows it?

The default keymap is this:

{ "keys": ["ctrl+l"], "command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "line"} }

The problem is that when you select the line and begin replacing it with new code, the line that follows it moves up to the current line.

I assume you replace "line" in the "args" section with something else, but I can't seem to find this documented anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also could not find any example/documentation of selecting the current line without selecting the next line. Fortunately we can make a command that does this.

1. Create a file `User/my_utilities.py`. I stick all my random self-developed ST commands here.
2. Stick this in it:

   ```
   import sublime, sublime_plugin

   class MyExpandSelectionToLine(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
       def run(self, edit):
           regions = []
           for s in self.view.sel():
               line = self.view.line(sublime.Region(s.begin(), s.end()))
               if line.end() == s.end():
                   # we're at the end of a line, so select the next line
                   line = self.view.line(sublime.Region(s.end(), s.end() + 1))
               regions.append(line)
           for r in regions:
               self.view.sel().add(r)
   ```
3. In your User .sublime-keymap file, add this:

   ```
   `{ "keys": ["super+l"], "command": "my_expand_selection_to_line" }`
   ```

If on Windows you'll want `["ctrl+l"]` instead of `["super+l"]`

This overrides the default command binding for selecting a line to run the new command we just wrote.

Comment: Just to add to your answer, these are the available arguments for expand_selection: `bol, hardbol, eol, hardeol, bof, eof, brackets, line`.  More info here: http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/commands.html

Comment: Hm. None of these work for me: `bol, hardbol, eol, hardeol, bof, eof`. There are a few options that aren't documented there that do work, however: `indentation, tags`. I also found `scope` in the default keybindings but could not get it to work.

Comment: I had the same issue as Matt with 'eol', 'hardeol', etc., but the Commands link is a great reference -- thanks for posting.

Comment: Interesting.  Well, the unofficial docs are open-source and available on github here: https://github.com/SublimeText/UnofficialDocs  So if you find any more errors, feel free to send a pull request with the changes.

Comment: And now we have the official docs:
http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/commands

Arguments to `expand_selection`: `line`, `word`, `scope`, `brackets`

Answer (score 3):

Matt's solution works great, and another option is to record a macro and assign it to `ctrl+l`. This has the added benefit of only selecting to the first code character, so the new line is indented at the same level as the line you're replacing.

Here's the macro:

```
[
    {
        "args":
        {
            "extend": false,
            "to": "bol"
        },
        "command": "move_to"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "extend": true,
            "to": "eol"
        },
        "command": "move_to"
    }
]
```

This gets saved as MacroName.sublime-macro in `\Packages\User` (Windows).

Here's the keymap:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+l"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/MacroName.sublime-macro"} }
```

Since this takes away the ability to select additional lines by repeating `ctrl+l`, I also moved the `expand_selection` command to `ctrl+shift+l` (which overrides `split_selection_into_lines`):

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+l"], "command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "line"} },
```

So now to select the current line, select `ctrl+l` and then to expand the selection to the lines beneath, press `ctrl+shift+l` for as many lines as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to my "Key Bindings - User" did it for me:

```
{ "keys": ["shift+end"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "hardeol", "extend": true} }
```

Credit: http://wesbos.com/sublime-text-end-of-line-wrap/