# How do I prevent ⌘L from selecting the line indentation in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

Disclaimer: I'm very new to both ST2 and coding.
Running Mac OSX.

I am trying to find a way to get the ⌘L command to NOT select:

- The next line
- Indentations

Here's an example:

[image]

I found a partial answer to this question on Stack overflow already:
[ST2 Keymap: Args for "expand_selection"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928799/st2-keymap-args-for-expand-selection)

That solves the problem of NOT selecting the next line, but indentations are still a bother. That solution is enabled in the GIF I linked.

I feel stumped.

Comment: Try instead: CMD + left arrow, CMD + SHIFT + right arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following as a plugin. Note this will not select the next line if the cursor is at the end like the other post, but that isn't the behavior I would expect. You can modify this so it will do that if you want.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class TrimmedLineSelect(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        line_regions = []
        new_line_regions = []
        view = self.view
        cursors = view.sel()
        for cursor in cursors:
            line_regions.append(view.line(cursor))

        for region in line_regions:
            line_content = view.substr(region)
            full_length = len(line_content)
            stripped_length = len(line_content.lstrip())
            num_removed = full_length - stripped_length
            new_region = sublime.Region(region.begin() + num_removed, region.end())
            new_line_regions.append(new_region)

        view.sel().clear()
        for region in new_line_regions:
            view.sel().add(region)
```

The command will be `trimmed_line_select`