# How to make Sublime Text - Command L select only current line (not move down)

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

This is kind of an obscure question but a lot of times I use Command+L to quickly highlight text and then immediately start typing over it.  This doesn't work because when you use Command+L Sublime will highlight the current line,but it will also place the cursor on the line  below the current line in the process. Then, if you start immediately typing, you will pull the following line up and adjacent to what you are typing.

Is there a known way to stop the "place cursor on following line" behavior of Command+L?

Comment: This has come up before on StackOverflow and it looks like there are solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928799/st2-keymap-args-for-expand-selection

Comment: Yep that did it, thanks.  I did try to search SO first but my choice of keywords wasn't working out apparently :)